# How to change color of a character while tailing and tr

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, tail, tr

I regularly use this command line but I would like to change the color of the "|" to green in the output.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```
tail -f file.log  | tr '\001' '|' | grep TEST
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can with `tr` because the replacement set is truncated to the length of the match set, and changing color requires some control characters.

Not impossible with `sed` tho:

```
tail -f file.log  | sed s/\001/\\x1b[32m\|\\x1b[0m/g
```

`1b` is hex for octal `33`, oft seen in things like color prompts because the shell likes octal (but to get "unprintable" control characters through `sed`, use hex).  E.g., to just print a green bar:

```
echo -e "\033[32m|\033[0m"
```

The control sequences are "ANSI escape sequences", see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for details (32 is green foreground, 0 is reset).  Octal 33 = decimal 27 = the ASCII 'ESC' character, hence "escape sequence".

Comment: What does the 'a' stand for in sed s/a/... ?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf Good question...I'm guessing I meant to explain that as whatever character (as in "replace a with b") ???  But the OP got it so I never noticed.  Anyway, I've replaced that with `\001` to match the question.

Comment: No wonder I didnt find anything about anywhere =) Alright, thx.

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -f file.log  | sed -n '/TEST/s/\x1/\x1b[32m|\x1b[0m/gp'
```

- `-n` tell sed to suppress the output by default (but the final `p` will tell to print the matched rows, a sort of grep)
- `/TEST/` select only lines that match (as grep)
- `s` to replace `\x1` (`\x` is the shell escape for hexadecimal values) with `\x1b[32m|\x1b[0m`.

  - `\x1b[` start an [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)
  - `32` is the color green for the foreground text
  - `\x1b[0m` reset the foreground color
  - `g` for global, replace very occurrence

You may set it in your `.bashrc` as a function (*not tested*)

```
loggrep() {
   sed -n "/$1/s/\x1/\x1b[32m|\x1b[0m/gp"
}
```

Comment: You are too fast :)

Comment: I would go with a more portable version of: `tail -f file.log | sed -n '/TEST/ "s/\x1/$(tput setaf 2)|$(tput sgr0)/gp"`, which will get the appropriate code for your term type for "green" and "reset"

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how your command can work since (at least on my system) `tail -f` cannot be piped twice since the second program you pipe to (`grep` in your case) waits until the input has finished before printing results.

Anyway, the standard method is what goldilocks suggested, using [ANSI escape color sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). Since I do this very often, I have written a little script that will color whatever string you give it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my %opts;
getopts('hic:l:',\%opts);
    if ($opts{h}){
      print<<EoF; 
Use -l to specify the pattern(s) to highlight. To specify more than one 
pattern use commas. 

-l : A Perl regular expression to be colored. Multiple expressions can be
     passed as comma separated values: -l foo,bar,baz
-i : makes the search case sensitive
-c : comma separated list of colors;

EoF
      exit(0);
    }

my $case_sensitive=$opts{i}||undef;
my @color=('bold red','bold blue', 'bold yellow', 'bold green', 
           'bold magenta', 'bold cyan', 'yellow on_magenta', 
           'bright_white on_red', 'bright_yellow on_red', 'white on_black');
if ($opts{c}) {
   @color=split(/,/,$opts{c});
}
my @patterns;
if($opts{l}){
     @patterns=split(/,/,$opts{l});
}
else{
    $patterns[0]='\*';
}

# Setting $| to non-zero forces a flush right away and after 
# every write or print on the currently selected output channel. 
$|=1;

while (my $line=<>) 
{ 
    for (my $c=0; $c<=$#patterns; $c++){
    if($case_sensitive){
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/){
           $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ge;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/i){
          $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ige;
        }
      }
    }
    print STDOUT $line;
}
```

If you save it as `color` in a directory that is in your `$PATH` and make it executable (chmod +x /usr/bin/color), you can color lines from your error log like this:

```
tr '\001' '|' < file.log | color -l "\|"
```

As written, the script has predefined colors for 10 different patterns, so giving it a comma separated list as I have in the example above will color each of the patterns matched in a different color.

Answer (score 1):

To colorize the `|` character, pipe to

```
sed -e "s/\|/$(tput setaf 2)\\0$(tput sgr0)/g"
```

The terminal capabilities `setaf` and `sgr0` are mentioned in `terminfo(5)`.